# Ghost stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Do some stackexchange sites named after common dictionary words already exist? I was able to visit and create accounts in [movies.stackexchange.com](http://movies.stackexchange.com) and [comics.stackexchange.com](http://comics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you view source on those two sites, you will find the following near the top.

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

I do not have a link handy (I'll instead rely on [display of seniority!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65075/ghost-stackexchange-sites/65078#65078)), but this is an indication that the website is a Stack Exchange 1.0 website, from the original model. The administrators for those sites date back to December '09 and October '09, so they predate Area 51 and thus it does not look like some manner of pre-private-beta peek. Just some otherwise abandoned sites that were never fully established, it appears.

Answer (score 3):

These are SE 1.0 sites. You can tell by checking the source:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

These sites are part of the reason Jeff & Joel canned the original SE offering and went with Area 51.